# How to get index from itertools.product

Tags: python

```
# loop through every NxN cell in the target image
    for (blk_row, blk_col) in itertools.product(xrange(0, height - 
      (cell_size - 1), cell_size), xrange(0, width - (cell_size - 1), cell_size)):
```

where N = cellsize, would it be valid to divide by cellsize to get an index?

Comment: Don't know; try it?

Comment: Aren't `blk_row`, `blk_col` already the indexes in your cell? Or are you trying to get the number of times the for loop has repeated at that step.

Comment: Both `range()`s are in step size `cell_size` so you can divide by `cell_size` - no idea if this results in an `index` - that depends on what all these variables mean.

Comment: number of times the for loop, yes thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the index for any iterator use `enumerate`:

```
for index, (blk_row, blk_col) in enumerate(itertools.product(
                                           xrange(0, height - (cell_size - 1), cell_size), 
                                           xrange(0, width - (cell_size - 1), cell_size))):
```

Answer (score 0):

Divided by the cell_size seemed to work, fingers crossed.